# ASP.NET Core & OpenID Connect Redirect to External Identity Provider

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

I've built an Identity Provider using OpenID Connect to provide authentication and authorization leveraging OAuth2 access tokens. The authorization workflow on the server works; however, I can't seem to get my ASP.NET Core client to automatically redirect to the OpenID Connect provider when authentication fails. I currently just receive a 401.

Here is my startup.cs:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication();

        var options = new OpenIdConnectOptions
                          {
                              Authority = "http://localhost:63467",
                              AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                              AutomaticChallenge = true,
                              AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet,
                              AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
                              ClientId = "2",
                              ClientSecret = "alskghalsd",
                              Configuration =
                                  new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
                                      {
                                          AuthorizationEndpoint =
                                              "http://localhost:63467/connect/authorize",
                                          TokenEndpoint =
                                              "http://localhost:63467/connect/token"
                                      },
                              PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/",
                              ResponseType = "Code",
                              RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout",
                              UseTokenLifetime = true,
                              SaveTokens = true,
                              SignInScheme = "Cookies",
                              RequireHttpsMetadata = false
                          };
        options.Scope.AddRange(new[] { "openid name role profile" });
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by hosting an application as an Identity endpoint using IdentityServer and configured my client accordingly.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc(
            opts =>
                {
                    // custom api exception filter
                    opts.Filters.Add(typeof(ApiExceptionFilter));
                });
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(
            options =>
                {
                    options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
                    options.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
                    options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = false;
                });

        services.AddSingleton(this.Configuration);
        services.AddIdentityServer();
    }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {  
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies" });
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        // get values from config
        IConfigurationSection clientSettings = this.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:ClientSettings");
        string[] scopes = clientSettings["Scope"].Split(' ');
        var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
                          {
                              AuthenticationScheme = clientSettings["AuthenticationScheme"],
                              SignInScheme = clientSettings["SignInScheme"],
                              Authority = clientSettings["Authority"],
                              ClaimsIssuer = clientSettings["ClaimsIssuer"],
                              RequireHttpsMetadata =
                                  clientSettings.GetValue<bool>("RequireHttpsMetadata"),
                              ClientId = clientSettings["ClientId"],
                              ClientSecret = clientSettings["ClientSecret"],
                              ResponseType = clientSettings["ResponseType"],
                              GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = clientSettings.GetValue<bool>("GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint"),
                              SaveTokens = clientSettings.GetValue<bool>("SaveTokens")
                          };
        foreach (var scope in scopes)
        {
            oidcOptions.Scope.Add(scope);
        }

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

I'll wait a while before marking this as the answer to allow others to provide alternative solutions.